# Conda failed to solve environment on a fresh installation

Tags: python, conda, spyder, miniconda

I've encountered a strange issue with Conda on a fresh installation of Python. I recently installed Miniconda3, and created a new environment using it. Then, when I tried to install Spyder in said new environment, the following message appeared:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

This is a completely new installation of Miniconda3, so I do not understand why such an error is cropping up.

I ran the following commands in order to create the new environment and install Spyder:

```
>>> conda create -n new-env [answered y when prompted]
>>> conda install -n new-env spyder
```

My current `base` environment has the following packages:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h2bbff1b_1003
ca-certificates           2020.10.14                    0
certifi                   2020.6.20          pyhd3eb1b0_3
cffi                      1.14.3           py38hcd4344a_2
chardet                   3.0.4           py38haa95532_1003
conda                     4.9.2            py38haa95532_0
conda-package-handling    1.7.2            py38h76e460a_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
cryptography              3.2.1            py38hcd4344a_1
idna                      2.10                       py_0
menuinst                  1.4.16           py38he774522_1
openssl                   1.1.1h               he774522_0
pip                       20.2.4           py38haa95532_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38h2bbff1b_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pyopenssl                 19.1.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.5                h5fd99cc_1
pywin32                   227              py38he774522_1
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py38he774522_1
setuptools                50.3.1           py38haa95532_1
six                       1.15.0           py38haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.33.0               h2a8f88b_0
tqdm                      4.51.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   1.25.11                    py_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_3
wheel                     0.35.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
```

Comment: I don't see any error. Also, please include the actual commands that led to the issue.

Comment: Is "```failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.```" not considered an error? It was my first time seeing it. Also, I've updated the question to include your suggestions. :)

Comment: No, that is very typical. Starting with Conda v4.6 (or maybe it was 4.7?), the solver was reworked to solve in two stages. Stage one, the "frozen solve", attempts to satisfy the constraints without changing any already installed packages. This usually fails, hence, the message. Then it moves on to stage two, which allows current packages to be changed (usually upgraded, but sometimes down). The other failure (`repodata.json`) is likely due to it needing to update the info on available packages in the repositories. But still not an error *per se*. Did it eventually install Spyder?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the what is going on with Conda, merv! Yes, it did eventually install Spyder. Good to know that it's not an error, but actually a feature.